# std::numeric_limits::quiet_NaN() vs. std::nan() vs. NAN

Tags: c++11, floating-point, nan, cmath

I was surprised by the number of C++ facilities to represent quiet NaN value. I found three standard ways:

1. `std::numeric_limits<T>::quiet_NaN()` - generic, and I thought it was the chosen one
2. `std::nan`, `std::nanf`, `std::nanl` - family of functions accepting `const char*` argument
3. `NAN` - a macro, "which evaluates to a quiet not-a-number"

*Each* of these were introduced in C++11. I have several questions regarding this:

1. What does `const char*` argument stand for in `std::nan` and co? How it is used?
2. Why the hell we need to add a *macro* in C++11, while we already added a generic trait class for this purpose? (Is it for compatibility with C?)
3. What is the one I should use by default? (I suppose this is first)

Comment: The char is used to specify what Nan you want.. The interpretation is unspecified (iirc) but on my linux box the bytes are used to initialize the Nan "payload", designed primarily to help diagnose where specific Nans originate from.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`std::nan`, `std::nanl` and `std::nanf` [are inherited from the C Math library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nan); so is the [NAN macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/NAN). They all live in C's [`<math.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath). As @NicolBolas suggests, however, they were only introduced in C++11 because they were not part of ANSI C, but rather of C99, a newer version of the C language standard. The C++ standards committee was making an effort to 'update' the C compatibility, so to speak.

[`std::numeric_limits<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/quiet_NaN) was designed for C++ itself (well before C++11), and that's what I'd use.

So, the bottom line answer is: C99 compatibility.

Comment: I think it also resides in <limits> header